# I find it hard to make friends at work after a betrayal by a close friend

Tags: ethics, relationships

I did not trust people easily until the last year. So, I decided to make new friends and not to judge them in the early days. I made this new friend who became close to me in no time. We shared everything from gossip to solving assignments. And then one day I found out he lied to me all this time. I went on being normal and trying to collect more evidences which eventually I did manage to get. I could not forgive him. I just tried to shout at him and vent it out but all my actions were futile. I just stopped thinking about it. He also did not agree to any of the allegations and was not even interested to explain. I felt I had made a fool of myself.

Nonetheless, I  still do make new friends. But I am just not able to confide in them or I always feel they would do something like he did, even the ones at my new workplace. So I have minimised sharing my personal details or ongoings with anyone. Even my best friends with whom I once shared all the stuff, I find it difficult to do the same now.

I have no clue why is this happening. I want to make close buddies. Is this really a heartbreak in friendship? How do I become the same person as before? Would I never be able to trust people, ever? Also, is it unethical to behave so in my part?

Comment: "And then one day I found out he lied to me all this time." About what? It sounds like you're talking about more than friendship.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: This might make more sense in the beta for the interpersonal skills SE site that's coming out, though I believe it's currently a closed beta.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be best buddies with your co-workers in order to do your job.  Therefore there is no ethical dilemma here, at least not as it pertains to the workplace.

I don't think you really *need* to share the intimate details of your life with the people you work with, either.  Especially not if you work in an industry with a lot of turnover, like software (although I recognize that you didn't actually specify your industry, and it's not really super-relevant.)

I would suggest you try to make a point of going out for lunch with your co-workers, at least once a week, if possible.  Just hang out and have fun.  Don't worry about sharing anything about yourself, just let yourself *be* with them in the moment.  You may not make any lifelong friends this way, but it should be more than enough to make the workplace cordial.

If you need help making friends *outside the workplace* and want advice about how to construct deeper and more meaningful relationships... That's not really on-topic for Workplace.SE.  However, you might try finding a social group that does something you're interested in - dancing, board gaming, knitting, whatever - and start attending meetings there to meet new people.  Maybe some of your co-workers would know of such groups in the vicinity of your office.